# Flutter PageView is not jumping to other page but scrolling works

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-pageview

I am simply trying to navigate to another page inside my `pageView` on a `callback`. This is my setup:

```
  final PageController _pageController = PageController(
    initialPage: 0,
    keepPage: true,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext rootContext) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            CustomAppBar(
              onPageTapped: (int pageIndex) {
                _toPage(pageIndex);
              },
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: PageView(
                onPageChanged: (int index) {
                  print('changed: $index');
                },
                controller: _pageController,
                children: [
                  StartPage(),
                  AdditionPage(),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  _toPage(int index) {
    print('topage: $index');
    _pageController.animateTo(
      index.toDouble(),
      curve: Curves.easeInOut,
      duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
    );
  }
```

The weird thing is that I can scroll to the second page (`AdditionPage`) but my `_jumpTo` function is not working. I printed the `index` inside it and its always the correct value. But my controller does not want to navigate to the other page...

What am I missing here? I feel like its something stupid...

Answer (score 0):

Use `animateToPage` instead of `animateTo`

`animateTo` is inherited from `ScrollController`, and controls the offset of the view in pixels.